# What's the meaning of "cross-connect"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found this word in the Github [guide](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#notifications), and I don't understand it.

It is used in this context (emphasis added):

> By using @mentions and references inside of Issues, you can notify other GitHub users & teams, and **cross-connect** issues to each other. These provide a flexible way to get the right people involved to resolve issues effectively, and are easy to learn and use. They work across all text fields on GitHub — they’re a part of our text formatting syntax called GitHub Flavored Markdown.

What does *cross-connect* mean?

Comment: *Cross* indicates that the connections are between two different groups (the users and teams, if I'm understanding it correctly).  One could also provide links within a single group, and those wouldn't be "cross".  (Maybe a hair unhappy,  but not cross.)

Comment: I don't know what exactly it means on Github. To me, *cross-connection* implies ***bi-directionality***: if you have cross-connected Issue A to Issue B, then Issue B is also connected to Issue A. This is different from a *reference* or a *link*, where linking A to B does not automatically link B to A.

Comment: @michael-hor257k description is 100% correct. A has a "pointer" to B. And B has a "pointer" to A.  I am using "pointer" to mean a note or reference.

Comment: It needs to be understood here that there is no precise definition of this term.  It is used many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are two issues in a repository and these issues are connected to each other in a way that the first issue causes the second issue.
For example, if in the first issue you mention the second issue of that repository, you are making a connection between these two issues and indicating that they are relevant to each other. This is called 'cross-connect'ing the things.